# About how many prime exponents $n$ can we expect for ($a^n-b^n$)/($a-b$)?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the probablity that a prime $n$ will appear on the table listed on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Other_generalized_Mersenne_primes) from $a$ $=$ $1$ to $12$ and $b$ $=$ $-12$ to $12$? (The table with numbers $n$ such that ($a^n − b^n$)/($a − b$) is prime)

For example, the primes $21701$, $25561$, $44497$ appear on the list while $13553$, $28817$, $34057$ do not.

Every prime $<$ $100$ appears at least once and probably every prime $<$ $1000$ too (correct me if I am wrong about this). What about larger primes, say those $<$ $10^{30}$? Of all the primes less than that range (about ($10^{30}$)/(log $10^{30}$)) how many are expected to appear on the table (for Generalized Mersenne Primes ($a^n-b^n$)/($a-b$) (for $a$ $=$ $1$ to $12$ and $b$ $=$ $-12$ to $12$?) Thanks for help.